# How to block closing tinybox from outer click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Does anybody know how can I block tinybox to close by clicking the outer of popup page? 
Thanks for your interest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

```
// your usual code here
TINY.box.show({...});

// for IE < 9 you'll have to implement getElementsByClassName - or use a library
document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].onclick=null;
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much draevor. Is there a chance for me to ask a very simple quest too?

Comment: It's better to ask directly than to ask if you can ask :)

Comment: :)
After popup window loads, when I scroll down to page, or resize the page, the mask does not fill all the page. It just masks the first width and height of page. 
Thanks again...

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much you can do about that (it caches the width and the height of the body after the first run), except for changing the source code of the library directly (not a very good option). I would suggest using another library, as there are many options and much better written.

Comment: Ok, got it draevor. Thanks for your interest again.

Comment: by the way, when i checked the code and changed, m.onclick = g.onclick = TINY.box.hide to g.onclick = TINY.box.hide; 
It worked too.

Comment: Of course, but you should change the library code directly - if the library will be updated in the future you'll have to remember to make the changes again.

Comment: Do you know how can I handle resizing mask problem in the library too?

Comment: You've got to start with `window.onresize=function() { TINY.box.mask(); };`, but then you'll have to look more at the code to see how to make it actually update - didn't see it at first glance.

Comment: Ok, I have handled it too.
Change 'mask: function () { m.style.height = $(document).height + 'px'; m.style.width = this.total(0) + 'px' },' to 'mask: function () { m.style.height = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px'; m.style.width = this.total(0) + 'px' },' and it is OK then.
Thanks again draevor.

Answer (score 0):

One time or permanent? If you want permanently disable you can use this piece of code after including Tinybox script;

```
TINY.box.hide = function() {};
```

Comment: Thank you too emre,
It also works if I want not to close popup, but I want my popup window to close only if I click on cancel button.